# Add Copy, PDF and Excel buttons to Datatable

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables

I'm pretty new at jquery, MVC, etc.  I'm designing a website in VS2015, MVC 5, Database First.  On my index page, I've successfully added Datatables with paging, sorting, searching and filtering.  Now I'm trying to add buttons to "automagically" copy or save to pdf or excel.  My buttons aren't showing up anywhere, not sure what the problem might be.  I have added a reference to buttons.dataTables.min.css in the layout page.  I'm wondering if I "installed" the extension correctly, but again, not sure.  Here's what my code that renders the datatable looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#instrumentsTable').dataTable({ stateSave: true, autoWidth: true, buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf']}).columnFilter(
        { (list of column specs)...
```

I have searched the internet exhaustively.  Found many references to TableTools, but that has been retired.  Any assistance and feedback is greatly appreciated.
~~~Tracy

Comment: You can try another plugin, like this one: http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php ...it seems quite simple to use too

Comment: Which version of datatables are you using? If less than version 1.10.8, you need TableTools - otherwise, are you referencing the buttons css/js files? http://datatables.net/download/release

Comment: I use TableTools with the latest version of Datatables for exactly this task you're describing and they work perfectly together. By far the simplest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working.  I had version 1.10.7 of Datatables, obtained through NuGet and it wasn't showing any upgrades available (re: 1.10.8).

So, I went to the following page http://datatables.net/download/index to "build" my own Datatables with extensions.  This is a great tool... after I selected the options I need, the download included 2 simple files with everything... script and css files.  That's all I had to reference in my page (after adding them to my project).  Here's what I included in my download:

```
DataTables (1.10.8)
Buttons
HTML5 Exports (required for local file saving)
JSZip (required for Excel button)
pdfmake (required for PDF button)
printview
```

I also selected in the packaging section:  minify, single file, and local files.

After including the downloaded script and css files into my project, here's the code that's working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#instrumentsTable').dataTable({ stateSave: true, autoWidth: true, dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: ['print', 'pdf', 'excel'] }).columnFilter(
        {... column filter stuff...
```